# How can I make an impulse so that point b moves away from point a in box2d/ cocos2diphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, math, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm applying an impulse on a box2d object with something like this:

```
b2Vec2 impulse = b2Vec2(4.0f, 15.0f);
body->ApplyLinearImpulse(impulse, body->GetWorldCenter());
```

I know this is probably high school math, and I promise I have made efforts to discover this for myself; please forgive my ignorance.

If I have objects a, b and c - and object a is at the midpoint of b and c, how can I create a Box2D impulse so that objects b and c move away from a at velocity v?

[image: scientific diagram drawn with great skill and focused intent]

Comment: Thanks. If programming doesn't work out I'm going to go into fine arts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

```
b2Vec2 impulseB = bodyB->GetPosition() - bodyA->GetPosition();
impulseB /= impulseB.Length();
impulseB *= predefinedScaleValue; // predefinedScaleValue is your velocity
b2Vec2 impulseC = -impulseB;
bodyB->ApplyLinearImpulse(impulseB, bodyB->GetWorldCenter());
bodyC->ApplyLinearImpulse(impulseC, bodyC->GetWorldCenter());
```

I hope it's clear what's going on here. If not, just ask :)

Comment: Works a treat thanks! I do get an error on line 2 "member reference b2Vec2 is not a pointer" but if I take it out things seem to work fine, what does this error mean?

Comment: This assumes that B and C are on exactly opposite sides of A. If not, you just need to repeat the first three lines for C to get impulseC.

Comment: Fixed line 2 - it should have been a dot instead of `->`. @iforce2d - The question says that object a is in the middle.

Comment: ah, so it does. I missed that.